# Amazon Hive JDBC Driver memory usage

Tags: jdbc, hive

Is there any known issue with Java memory usage when using the Amazon Hive driver :

```
com.amazon.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver
```

For example, the size of an underlying cache or anything else in the client ? I cannot control the request being sent to Hive ? Is there anything I should be aware of when using this driver regarding the memory usage ?